# Invoke JQuery method from Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm working on creating an Angular 2 front end on an existing project that previously just used JQuery. Is it possible to invoke a JQuery method inside of an Angular 2 component, when that JQuery function exists in a separate file? I'm writing my components in TypeScript, in case that is important to know.

For example, I have a JavaScript file called EditCheckBoxes.js with a method called `editCheckBoxes()`. In order for `editCheckBoxes()` to work, I need it to be invoked after a certain component is initiated. My attempted solution was this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    editCheckBoxes();
}
```

This code gives me the following error:

> Cannot find name 'editCheckBoxes'.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Also, I added `declare var $: any;` to my component file, so I am able to use JQuery within that component, but I'd rather not copy entire files into my components in order to use them.

EDIT:

The folder structure looks like this:

```
Plan
   app
      selling
         My Angular 2 component
   Scripts
      EditCheckBoxes.js
```

In my component, the import statment looks like this:  `import { editCheckboxes } from '../../Scripts/EditCheckboxes';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `editCheckboxes` method in your typescript file for it to be available.

To do that you first need to export the `editCheckboxes` function from EditCheckBoxes.js

```
export function editCheckboxes() { ... }
```

Next you should just import that function inside your component

```
import { editCheckBoxes } from './EditCheckBoxes';
```

Now it can be called in your component: `editCheckBoxes();`

Comment: This gives me a build error that says: "Cannot find module './EditCheckBoxes'

Answer (score 1):

In order to import function from js file you should at first export it like so:

```
// EditCheckBoxes.js
module.exports = function editCheckBoxes () { ... };
```

then add a `d.ts` file in same directory as your js-file with definition of your module that would be used by Typescript

```
// EditCheckBoxes.d.ts
declare function editCheckBoxes (): void;
export = editCheckBoxes;
```

then in your Typescript file you would specify your definition file, import your function and use it like so:

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/EditCheckBoxes.d.ts" />
import editCheckBoxes = require('../../Scripts/EditCheckBoxes');

ngOnInit (): void {
    editCheckBoxes();
}
```

Comment: This gives me a build error that says: "Cannot find module './EditCheckBoxes'

Comment: I added that to my post

Comment: excuse me for dumb assumption but does your filename match the one you specify in import statement?

Comment: Yes, sorry I had a typo when I edited my question. I'm not sure whether to include the .js extention when importing it though. If I don't include it, will it assume it's a TypeScript file?

Comment: Are you sure a JavaScript file can be imported into a TypeScript file?

Comment: So the only thing i put in EditCheckBoxes.d.ts is those two lines of code?

Comment: Yes, if you export only that function. Checked it, works fine.